# neo4j performance issues with many OR clauses

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have performance issues with one of my generated queries. The query looks something like this:

```
MATCH p=(n:Person)
WHERE n.first_name = 'John' AND n.middle_name = 'A' AND n.last_name = 'Smith'
   OR n.first_name = 'Joe' AND n.last_name = 'Man'
   OR n.last_name = 'Storm'
   OR n.first_name = 'Jonas' AND n.middle_name = 'Q' AND n.last_name = 'Son'
   ..
   .. # 20 more OR clauses
   ..
   ..
RETURN p
```

This query takes forever to run while the individual queries is very fast, e.g.:

```
MATCH p=(n:Person)
WHERE n.first_name = 'John' AND n.last_name = 'Smith'
RETURN p
```

..returns almost instantly.

I have indexes on all properties; `first_name`, `middle_name` and `last_name`.

Debugging this is hard since queries warms up the cache. A query that takes minutes to complete first may take seconds if run directly in succession.

**Is there a way that I can rewrite the query so that it goes faster?**

(I really don't want to run the individual queries in sequence since I want the result in one batch.)

Comment: what if you refactor your person nodes to include full name property and then do WHERE IN clause?

Comment: @TomažBratanič I want to be able to search for the individual components of the name. If I merge all properties into one I will loose precision. I can maybe get away with doing a regex search, but would that be faster than the current solution?

Comment: You can still do both, but you avoid full name search consisting of 3 and statements... also check https://maxdemarzi.com/2020/08/24/faux-bitmap-indexes-in-neo4j/